# ¿Cómo calculo una linea de tendencia con postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, math

Suponiendo que tengo una tabla con valores X y Y, debo calcular una linea de tendencia con las siguientes formulas:
Siendo n la cantidad de datos

- a = n.Σxy
- b = Σx.Σy
- c = n.Σ(x^2)
- d = (Σx)^2
- **m = (a-b)/(c/d)**
- e = Σy
- f = m.Σx
- **b = (e-f)/n**
- **y= mx + b**

Lo ideal es hacer el código lo más legible posible. No se si por temas de optimización sea util crear más tablas temporales y hacer los calculos en más pasos o en su lugar realizar una formula larga y luego remplazar los valores.

```
    
    drop table if exists tmp_b_linea;
    create temp table tmp_b_linea as
    with w as ( select
                    count(x)::float n
                    ,(count(x)*sum(x*y))::float a
                    ,(sum(x) * sum(y))::float b
                    ,(count(x) * sum(power(x,2)))::float c
                    ,(power(sum(x),2))::float d
                    ,(sum(y))::float e
                    ,(sum(x))::float sum_x
                from test.tbl_funcion)
    select
        w.*
        ,((a-b)/nullif ((c-d),0)) m
        ,((a-b)/nullif ((c-d),0))*sum_x f
        ,(e-(((a-b)/nullif ((c-d),0))*sum_x))/n b1
    from w;
    --select * from tmp_b_linea
    select
        x
        ,y
        ,(m*x)+b1 y1
    from test.tbl_funcion, tmp_b_linea;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria una versión más corta:

```
create temp table tmp_calc as
select 
    ((count(x)*sum(x*y))-(sum(x) * sum(y)))/((count(x) * sum(power(x,2)))-(power(sum(x),2))) m
    ,(sum(y)-(sum(x)*((count(x)*sum(x*y))-(sum(x) * sum(y)))/((count(x) * sum(power(x,2)))-(power(sum(x),2)))))/count(x) b
from test.tbl_funcion;
--select * from tmp_calc

select
    x
    ,y
    ,(m*x)+b y1
from test.tbl_funcion, tmp_calc;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).